# A general question about Cauchy operators

Tags: functional-analysis, singular-integrals

I want to familiarize myself more with the Cauchy operators. As soon as I say "operator" I have to specify on which space, Okay, that should be my first question:

On which spaces the Cauchy operators are usually considered ? $L^{1}([a,b]), L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, $L^{2}([a,b]), L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, $\ldots$  , $L^{\infty}([a,b])$, $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

As a simple check, I wanted to check $L^{\infty}([a,b])$, let $f \in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ ,$f \neq 0$, and consider its Cauchy transform $$C[f](x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i } \int^{b}_{a} \frac{f(y)}{y-x}dy$$ $$\left| \ C[f](x) \ \right| = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \left|  \int^{b}_{a} \frac{f(y)}{y-x}dy \right| \leq \frac{||f||_{L^{\infty}}}{2 \pi } \left|  \int^{b}_{a} \frac{1}{y-x}dy \right|= \frac{||f||_{L^{\infty}}}{2 \pi } \left|\ln|\frac{b-x}{a-x}| \right|  $$ but the right hand side is not bounded.

Does it mean that $C$ is not an operator on $L^{\infty}([a,b])$ ? How about other spaces ?

Comment: This is more commonly considered to be a Hilbert transform. One thing that you are missing is that these integrals are *principal value* integrals. This allows you to actually do these integrals in a lot of cases. The Hilbert transform is somewhat distributional in nature because of the non-integrability of the integral kernel, though the distribution theory needed to treat it is fairly minimal. In fact, it's often subsumed by considering things formally. Its relationship to the Fourier transform is very nice.

Comment: can you delete the i from your equations, please

Comment: @Hamza I did ! thanks,

Comment: @the8thone not from definition but only from the last calculus.

Comment: Because usually we consider the Cauchy transform from the set of complex borel measure to a subspace of analytic  function more precisely to the espace $\cap_{0<p<1} H^p$ where $H^p$ is the classical Hardy space, for more information you can see https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~wross/pdf/cauchy.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the operator you are looking at is usually called the Hilbert transform (a generalization of the Cauchy integral, and a first example of a singular integral operator).

I am not sure I have a full answer for you, but I would suggest to take a look at Chapter 3 of ["Fourier Analysis"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821725) by Duoandikoetxea.
As also mentioned in the comments, you need to define your operator using principal values. I won't go too much into details, since you can look them up in the book I have mentioned.

The Hilbert transform $H$ of a Schwartz function $f$ is
$$
H(f)= \frac{1}{\pi} \operatorname{p.v.}\frac{1}{x} *f,
$$
where $\operatorname{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}$ is a tempered distribution defined by 
$$
\operatorname{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}(\phi)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\, dx,
$$
where $\phi$ is a Schwartz function. 
Then the above definition for $H$ works for Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and can be easily extended to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. 
Then we have Riesz-Kolmogorov theorem:

> For $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the following assertions are true:
>
> 1. $H$ is weak $(1,1)$: 
>      $$ \left|\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |Hf(x)|>\lambda\}\right|\leq \frac{C}{\lambda} \|f\|_1 $$
> 2. $H$ is strong $(p,p)$, for $p \in (1,\infty)$:
>      $$ \|H(f)\|_p \leq C \|f\|_p. $$

This allows us to extend $H$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, for $p\in [1,\infty)$. For a definition of weak $L^p$, I suggest to look at Folland's book ["Real Analysis"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), Chapter 6.